# How to evaluate functions in GDB?

Tags: function, gdb, evaluation

I wonder why evaluate function doesn't work in gdb? In my source file I include, when debugging in gdb, these examples are wrong evaluations.

```
(gdb) p pow(3,2)

$10 = 1

(gdb) p pow(3,3)

$11 = 1

(gdb) p sqrt(9)

$12 = 0
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My guess is that the compiler and linker does some magic with those particular functions. Most likely to increase performance.

If you absolutely need `pow()` to be available in gdb then you can create your own wrapper function:

```
double mypow(double a, double b)
{
    return pow(a,b);
}
```

Maybe also wrap it into a `#ifdef DEBUG` or something to not clutter the final binary.

BTW, you will notice that other library functions can be called (and their return value printed), for instance:

```
(gdb) print printf("hello world")
$4 = 11
```

Comment: Correct answer is given below by anon

Comment: @mattypiper "given below by anon" needs a link in that comment. I think you intended to point to [anon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398488/257924) .

Answer (score 37):

The syntax for calling a function in gdb is

```
call pow(3,2)
```

Type

```
help call
```

at the gdb prompt for more information.

Comment: Thanks! But call is still not correctly working


(gdb) call sqrt(9)


$14 = 0


(gdb) call pow(3,3)


$15 = 1

Comment: print will also call functions. In fact, I think the only difference is that call won't clutter the output when calling void functions

Answer (score 32):

You need to tell gdb that it will find the return value in the floating point registers, not the normal ones, in addition to give the parameters the right types.

I.e.:

> (gdb) p ((double(*)())pow)(2.,2.)
>
> $1 = 4

Comment: That's odd I get a value of `$1 = 2`

Comment: Hello! I am an idiot and have been bashing my head open to figure out what the hell does double(*) mean?? I thought it meant a function pointer that can "return double pointer, and takes void args". So I tried reconverting to ((double*)())pow)(2.,2.) -- failed! Why?

Comment: @BebeCarabina I feel your frustration: I desire to avoid this typecasting-induced severe head-trauma. I posted a related question at [How to evaluate functions in GDB without painful typecasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60839314/257924) to see if there is any solution.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, at least on my LINUX implementation of gcc, many of the math functions are replaced with variants specific to the types of their arguments via some fancy substitutions pulled in by math.h and bits/mathcalls.h (included from within math.h).  As a consequence, functions like pow and exp are called instead as `__pow` or `*__GI___exp` (your results may vary depending on the types of the arguments and perhaps the particular version).

To identify what exactly the function is that is linked in to my code I put a break at a line where just that function is called, e.g. have a line in my code with `b=exp(c);`.  Then I run in gdb up till that break point and then use the "step" command to enter the call from that line.  Then I can use the "where" command to identify the name of the called routine.  In my case that was `*__GI___exp`.

There are probably cleverer ways to get this information, however, I was not able to find the right name just by running the preprocessor alone (the -E option) or by looking at the assembly code generated (-s).

Comment: I know this is old, but if someone comes looking, here goes: For me it worked to just do `p pow` which gave me: `$28 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff77ffbd0 <__pow>`

Answer (score 1):

```
NAME
   pow, powf, powl - power functions

SYNOPSIS
   #include <math.h>

   double pow(double x, double y);
```

You shouldn't pass an int in the place of a double

```
 call pow( 3. , 2. )
```

Also, passing a single argument is not enough, you need two arguments just like the function expects

```
 wrong: call pow ( 3. )
```

Comment: actually, passing ints work fine. not sure if it is just coincidence, but calling mypow (see my answer) with integers produce the correct result. I get no output from gdb when calling pow(2.0,2.0), but I do when calling mypow() with any numbers