# strcmp in gdb giving odd results

Tags: c, gdb, strcmp

In GDB (gnu v 7.1-ubuntu) I am getting really weird results when I try to use `strcmp` to determine if two strings are equal. `p strcmp("hello","hello")` is giving me the result `-145947168`.

Everything I try with `strcmp` or `strncmp` is returning `-145947168` in gdb. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (thanks to Carl for the pointer to a related answer in the comments):
See the answer to this question: [How to evaluate functions in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354731/gdb-evaluation-of-a-function)

Apparently sometimes the compiler optimizes out functions called from external libraries, and defining a function in code that calls the function of the external library you want access to in GDB will make it available.

I added this to my code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
int mystrcmp(char *a, char *b){
        return strcmp(a,b);
}
int mystrncmp(char *a, char *b, int n){
        return strncmp(a,b,n);
}
#endif
```

and then re-made with `-DDEBUG -g` to enable the compilation of those helper functions for my gdb debugging.

```
(gdb) p mystrcmp("hello","hello")
$1 = 0
(gdb) p strcmp("hello","hello")
$2 = -145947168
```

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354731/gdb-evaluation-of-a-function

Comment: Please also mention which version of GDB you're using.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the '\0' at the end of each string hence the reason gdb is providing garbage.

Comment: Yes Carl, thanks, it is related to that issue. The compiler was optimizing out strcmp, so when I added in a function to call strcmp in my code, and called that function from gdb, it works!