# Print the whole linked list in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, ubuntu, data-structures, gdb

I have a linked list

```
struct node {
    data_t data;
    node_t *next;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *foot;
    node_t *curr;   // for iterator
    unsigned int size;
} list_t;
```

with this structure, let say 
I defined a list

```
list_t* myList;
```

How can I use GDB to print the whole linked list?

Comment: You could write a function to print the list and call it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354731/gdb-evaluation-of-a-function

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work (but untested):

```
define plist
  set var $n = $arg0->head
  while $n
    printf "%d ", $n->data
    set var $n = $n->next
  end
end

(gdb) plist myList
```

You could put `plist` into `~/.gdbinit`

Comment: @TimothyLeung Cut/paste the code at the `(gdb)` prompt, or use an editor to put into `~/.gdbinit`.

Answer (score 3):

GDB is scriptable in Python. You can [define your own pretty-printers](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) and do other useful things.

Better yet, use a standard container, GDB now supports printing those natively.