# debug C++ map in my IDE

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, qt-creator

I declare a map something like

```
std::map<int ,int > myMap;
```

then I use it something like

```
if (myMap.find(PID)!=myMap.end())
    myMap.find(PID)->second++;
else
    myMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(PID,1));
```

I debug it, then found in my debugger, it shows

```
myMap    <1 items>  std::map<int, int>
  [0]    <1 items>  int
```

But could not get any information related to the key and the value in     myMap, Is it normal?

Comment: What kind of IDE are you using?

Comment: Which debugger / IDE?

Comment: qt creator. but i could use this debugger to debug the other kind of map, and it shows the key and value.

Comment: 1st: Please use braces `{}` in your conditional code blocks 2nd: Debuggers usually come up poor with displaying c++ standard container structures, simple _"caveman debugging"_ (output to console or logfile) could probably be more helpful for this use case.

Comment: 3rd: A bit of an advanced version vs _"caveman debugging"_ would be to provide a particular _dump_ method that print's all the key/value pairs in a well readable format, and call this in the debugging session. Most of the modern debuggers support such _direct function call_ feature AFAIK ([see also here please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354731/gdb-evaluation-of-a-function))