# Using log2 in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, logarithm

I'm trying to debug a program with gdb, but gdb does not evaluate logarithms correctly:

```
(gdb) print log2(2)
$6 = 0
(gdb) print log2(1024)
$3 = 0
(gdb) print log2((double)1024)
$4 = 2
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to pass some flag to gdb?

Some info about my system:

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516
```

I compiled my program with `gcc -g -lm foo.c -o foo`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate functions in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354731/how-to-evaluate-functions-in-gdb)

Comment: The answer from anon (use `print ((double(*)())log2)(2.0)`) answers my question. Thanks!